# TFS2013 - Clone build definition for team project using git

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild, tf-cli

We want to clone a build definition for a TFS team project that uses git as its source code repository.

Our aim is to duplicate the existing build definition for a new branch.

When the build definition is cloned via the command line (Team Foundation Power Tools) like so

```
tfpt builddefinition /clone Team\Project_Nightly /collection:http://tfs01:8080/tfs/MyCollection
```

the resulting build definition looks OK at first but when editing the *Source Settings* it shows a completely different view with only *Working Folders* and no possibility to choose a branch.

Running `tfpt builddefinition /diff` shows no differences apart from name.

How can we clone a build definition for a TFS git repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the TFS Power Tools. Currently only builds using TFVC are supported.

It was [reported on Feb 15](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f/view/Discussions/4) (see the Q&A tab on the power tools gallery page), and I know the team is aware of it. I've got no idea when a fix is planned.

**Update:** I forgot. There's another extension you can use for cloning builds. The [TFS Build Manager extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f). It will correctly handle git builds for you.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks for the heads up.. I suppose there's no official site for reporting TFPT bugs or vote for features?

Comment: Apart from the QA panel? I don't think so.